# Convert object/array to array with comma and bracket

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

Our Result:

```
Array (
[0] => Array ( [0] => Province [1] => Party [2] => Age [3] => Name [4] => Gender )
[1] => Array ( [0] => Quebec [1] => NDP [2] => 22 [3] => Liu, Laurin [4] => Female )
[2] => Array ( [0] => Quebec [1] => Bloc Quebecois [2] => 22 [3] => Mourani, Maria [4] => Female ) 
)
```

I want a result looking like this: How to convert like this?

```
array(
['Province'=>'Quebec','Party'=>'NDP','Age'=>22,'Name'=>'Liu, Laurin','Gender'=>'Female'],
['Province'=>'Quebec','Party'=>'Bloc Quebecois','Age'=>43,'Name'=>'Mourani, Maria','Gender'=>'Female']
)
```

OR

```
array(
['Province', 'Party', 'Age', 'Name', 'Gender'],
['Quebec', 'NDP', 22, 'Liu, Laurin', 'Female'],
['Quebec', 'Bloc Quebecois', 43, 'Mourani, Maria', 'Female']
)
```

Comment: Your OR doesn't look any different to your original array

Comment: Please edit question and post th code you have, so maybe someone can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Pretty simple using an [array_combine()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php) to set the headers for each row, and just [walking the array](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-walk.php) setting those headers:

```
$headers = array_shift($myArray);
array_walk(
    $myArray,
    function(&$row) use ($headers) {
        $row = array_combine($headers, $row);
    }
);
```

Comment: That is good. But the result I provided does not have commas and quotes which is why the code does not run well.

Comment: DO you mean that you actually want a "string" that looks like `array(
['Province', 'Party', 'Age', 'Name', 'Gender'],
['Quebec', 'NDP', 22, 'Liu, Laurin', 'Female'],
['Quebec', 'Bloc Quebecois', 43, 'Mourani, Maria', 'Female']
)`? A string isn't an array, clarify your question